# Sidebar Ads in Responsive Layouts - How to make happy both advertises and readers ?

Tags: responsive-design

I have a blog and I make money from advertisements.

Currently, Advertisements are displayed on the sidebar only because I don't need to disturb readers when reading articles.

There are **two** 300*250 ads and **six** 125*125 ads are displaying currently.

My blog traffic is increasing month by month, but my clients (who give the advertisements to me) said that the traffic they got from my site are decreasing month by month.

I know the reason for that.

I have around just 10-20% traffic via mobile device in 2014.
But now I have more than 75% traffic comes from mobile device.

When responsive layouts, my sidebar displaying under the content like all other blogs. So readers won't click the ads.

I want to happy my clients (who give the advertisements to me), because I need to generate traffic for them. If they will go from my site, I can't generate money.

In other side, I need to happy readers also. So I can't display all advertisements before the content.

So is there any solution  for me?

Answer (score 1):

To be very honest, to satisfy the reader, as well as to satisfy the advertisement agency, in equal proportions, is never possible. Let me explain to you why I said that:

**Case 1**

Say, you want to generate maximum income. So you overload the mobile version's display with plenty of ads. You are stacking up ads over ads, and this will skyrocket your income via these ads, but it will fall drastically as days go by. Why? Because you have annoyed the reader with advertisements, until a point that he decides to quit trying to read the content. This means that your blog traffic will fall, and you will not get any visitors to even read the content, let alone visit the ads you have poured onto the viewport.

**Case 2**

On the other hand, you decide that the content that you shared is what you need to sell. This means that you will have to compromise on the ads, and this will increase the traffic into your blog, as the readers will feel comfortable reading the contents, and not repeatedly closing annoying advertisements. But this will not be an acceptable scenario for the advertisement agency.

So the real question is how to balance between the two. In the PC viewport, a sidebar advertisement is the best option, as long as it does not flash too much, or flicker, thereby distracting the viewer from reading the content. Since the mobile viewport has space restrictions, you might not want to create an ad-sidebar.

Here are a few options you can adopt, which *may* maintain a balance between the readers, as well as the ad sponsors:

1. > ***Pop-up Ads***

You could display a few ads as pop-ups, especially on page load. But keep in mind that there's nothing as irritating as a pop-up, from the reader's point of view. So keep pop-ups limited to one or two, unless it will adversely affect your blog traffic.

2. > ***Minimalistic side/bottom bar approach***

Use thin strips for showing your ads. I'm sure you've seen this being used in many apps and games. Take up a small portion, probably a twelfth or fifteenth of the screen dimension and show one-liner ads or banners. This can be constantly kept in the viewport without annoying the user. Initially the reader may get distracted, but he will not be bothered by it after a while.

**Note**:

You do not want to push the content with ads, or vice-versa. That isn't a good choice, at all. Ads that push the contents down will result in people leaving your blog, because they may not be aware of the content that followed the annoying ads. Likewise, if you push all the ads below the content, there is a chance that they may never been seen by the viewer.